# jquery document.ready not launched once

Tags: jquery, document-ready

As far as I know, $(document).ready(function () {}); should be launched once.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{    
    console.log("1");
    UpdateVehiculesRepartis();
    console.log("2");
    UpdateVehiculesEnAttente();
    console.log("3");
    UpdateVehiculesSurSite();
    console.log("4");
    Ajax_Maj_Info_Flux();
    console.log("5");
    InitComposants();
    setInterval("UpdateVehiculesEnAttente()", i_DELAI_RAFRAICHISSEMENT);   
});
```

When looking at the console, I see the 1\n 2\n 3\n 4\n 5. 
 But then it's launched again and again and again...
I don't understand how it can do this.

Comment: That's a typo, it should be `$(document).ready(function ()`, now you're looking for an element with the ID `#document`

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I edit my post.

Comment: @Dredall : is your problem solved now ?

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: The javascript page is used in an ASP.NET project, I don't think I can replicate this in jsfiddle. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Dredall: yeah you cant use server script in jsfiddle, but what you can do is that you can dump the generated html along with js script so that it can be simulated on jsfiddle. justt dump the relevant code

Answer (score 2):

You should write like this

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{    
    console.log("1");
    UpdateVehiculesRepartis();
    console.log("2");
    UpdateVehiculesEnAttente();
    console.log("3");
    UpdateVehiculesSurSite();
    console.log("4");
    Ajax_Maj_Info_Flux();
    console.log("5");
    InitComposants();
    setInterval("UpdateVehiculesEnAttente()", i_DELAI_RAFRAICHISSEMENT);   
});
```

Comment: The "#document" was a typo, I corrected my post.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by replacing :

```
$(document).ready(function(){})
```

by

```
$(window).load(function(){})
```

I still don't know why the document-ready was looping.